# Can use Blend SDK classes in code but not XAML (Prism Desktop)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism, expression-blend-4

I'm trying to use a `CallMethodAction` bound to a control in a WPF Window, using the method from the Prism library samples and documentation. For some reason, the XAML compiler refuses to acknowldge that the `Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core` namespace even exists. However, I have no problem using the same classes from the same namespace in the code-behind for that view.

In XAML I've tried both the canonical namespaces:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ic="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

as well as the CLR namespace:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
```

The namespace Intellisense pop-up browser displays the first namespace but neither the XML nor CLR namespaces for the second. In either case, the following XAML fails to compile:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Cancel">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ic:CallMethodAction />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

It has no problem finding the `Interaction.Triggers` tag, but complains that the `CallMethodAction` tag doesn't exist in the specified namespace. In fact, Intellisense on the `ic` namespace tag acts as if there is no such namespace. However, I do *not* get the error that the CLR namespace could not be found, which I do if I try to use a non-existant namespace.

However, in the constructor for this window, I can do this:

```
var x = new Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core.CallMethodAction();
```

That compiles and runs fine. How is that even possible?

Comment: have you tried removing and re-adding reference to Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll?

Comment: @surfen: You need `*.Interactivity.dll`...

Comment: @H.B. How am I supposed to use the Blend classes if I don't reference the Blend assembly?

Comment: @surfen that actually fixed it! any idea wtf happened? And can you post your explanation in the form of an answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: I think re-building the project would achieve the same as readding the reference, and you are right, for those classes you also need `Interaction`.

Comment: I did rebuild the project a few times; oddly enough, the object browser showed the classes but Intellisense did not :\ Oh well, all fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing and re-adding reference to `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll` and `*.Interactivity.dll`

It happened to me once but I don't know why. This is the way I solved it.